# the dbms assumes that a column name is a system variable inside the trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with three variables.  one is the amout, the other is a restricting.  Strict is the name of a column, but the system views it as a variable.  It is not.  It is not a reserved word either.

As this is an update, New is forbidden

```
 Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
 ERROR 1193: Unknown system variable 'strict'
 SQL Statement:
 CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER     `bibliotech`.`patronus_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `patronus` FOR EACH  ROW
BEGIN
 if amount >  5.65  
    then set strict =1;
elseif amount <5.65 
    then set strict =0;
end if;
ND
```

Comment: NEW is perfectly fine in a BEFORE UPDATE trigger; it is too late to change the values going into the table in an AFTER trigger. You must always use NEW and/or OLD to change and/or reference the field values of the row the trigger is operating on.

Comment: use of new or old is forbidden by mysql workbench and it won't be permitted by mysql dbms

Comment: @Steven Demonnin I think you missed the point you should be doing this in a BEFORE trigger setting NEW. values. - this is allowed in mysql

Comment: it needs to be after.   this is just a test, but in the real one I am updating the amount, and after the update I am testing the amount and depending on the amount I would be setting a restriction flag.  (more triggers on a different table)  I am changing the amount irregarles.  After that is done, I set the flag

Comment: You cannot use an AFTER trigger to alter the values of the row that trigger is operating on. If it needs to be after, then it cannot do what you want it to.